# Facebook graph api upgrade to v7.0, but login function failed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

currently I'm using fb graph api v2.12, which will expired at this month, so I upgrade to v7.0 in fb JS sdk just by changed version parameters, but login function failed. As we have a back-end service but it's not done by me, but sure front-end calls this back-end service, this service seems calls https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12, so I don't know if this back-end service version should align with FB js sdk version number, so all functions works well?

Comment: i am sure there is some error message?

Comment: yeah, @luschn, back-end service returns 401 unauthorized exception without other info, and it use https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12 as config, so I don't know if version number here should align with js sdk version no.